# IndexedDb : read and return the object

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Here is the code I'm using to retrieve informations from localdb :

```
function getById(idObject, typeObjectStore, cb_function) 
{
    idObject        = parseInt(idObject);
    var objectStore = db.transaction(typeObjectStore).objectStore(typeObjectStore);
    var request     = objectStore.get(idObject);

    request.onerror = function(event) {
        console.log('Error when loading ' + typeObjectStore);
    };

    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
        cb_function(request.result);
    };
}
```

I've read a lot of documentations and I can see that the retrieved content is usually printed directely in the cb_function (callback function).
I'd like to know if it's possible to return the object directly, so I would be able to exploit it in the rest of my code?

Doing something like this doesn't work, but you'll get what I'd like to do :

```
        request.onsuccess = function(event) {
            return(request.result);
        };
```

I'm afraid it's not possible considering the asynchronous way of retrieving the data, but I'd like to have a confirmation.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Bdloul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to return the value in this manner. The callback function is called asynchronously because request.onsuccess is called asynchronously. A return statement is synchronous. You need to know how to work with [asynchronous Javascript (AJAX)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) in order to use indexedDB. Writing AJAX is primarily accomplished with passing callbacks, a [continuation passing style (CPS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style).

Not everyone likes CPS, but it is a very powerful and simple way to express asynchronous operations in code, and sooner or later in every JavaScript programmer's career, you should learn about it.

If you are absolutely set on trying to return something, you can return a [promise](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/). Promises are not simple to learn how to use and will take a lot of understanding so proceed with caution.

Personally (my subjective opinion) I would not recommend trying to use Promises. I recommend learning more about [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). You can use bind to avoid writing nested functions. Bind is also difficult to learn how to use but it also presents an elegant way to avoid nested functions.

Comment: Thank, will take a look and bind and will keep printing in the meantime.